# Inheriting variables from classes with kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have a ScreenManagement and several classes in it that inherit the Screen class.

[image]

Each class has methods in which variables are in turn declared. One such variable that changes as you interact with the program is the login variable. How can I access any variable from these classes from any class on the image?

This is my MainProgram class with login variable:

[image]

How to get and use the login variable from the MainProgram class in the MessagePage class that has the same class structure?
In other words, I need to somehow pass variables between all pages in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `id: main_program` to instantiated child (`MainProgram:`) of `ScreenManagement:` so that you can reference all attributes declared in class MainProgram
2. To access the `login` attribute in `MainProgram` from `MessagePage`, use `root.manager.ids.main_program.login` in kv file. Use `self.manager.ids.main_program.login` in python code.
3. Add import statement, `from kivy.properties import StringProperty`
4. Declare a class attribute, `login = StringProperty('')` in class MainProgram.

## Snippets - kv file

```
ScreenManagement:
    RegistrationPage:
    PageOne:
    MainProgram:
        id: main_program
    MessagePage:
```

## Snippets - py file

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

...

class MainProgram(Screen):
    login = StringProperty('')
    ...
```

Comment: I only tried to get the login variable that is defined in the MainProgram class method, but he didn’t see it, he sees functions and variables that are declared immediately in the class but not variables declared in the method of this class. How to solve this?

Comment: You have to declare class attribute, `login` in class MainProgram. Please refer to updated post for details.

Comment: Thank! I figured it out